# mongoose findByIdAndUpdate updating only one field in the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to increment upvotes when the user clicks on some button and also store his stormpath User ID (req.user.href) inside an array.

**TRY 1 :**

```
if (newUpvoters = found_post[0].upvoters.indexOf(req.user.href) == -1) {
    Problem.findByIdAndUpdate(found_post[0].id,  
        { $push: { upvoters:  req.user.href }}
        , {$inc: { upvotes : 1 } }, function (err, post) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                res.json(post);
    })
}
```

**RESULT:**
Only upvoters array is correctly updated. Upvotes are not incremented.

**TRY 2 :**

```
Problem.findByIdAndUpdate(found_post[0].id,  
    {$inc: { upvotes : 1 } }, 
    { $push: { upvoters:  req.user.href }}, function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
})
```

**RESULT:**
Only Upvotes get incremented, upvoters array is not updated.

**TRY 3 :**

```
Problem.findByIdAndUpdate(found_post[0].id,  
    {$set :
        {$inc: { upvotes : 1 } , 
         $push: { upvoters:  req.user.href }}
    }, function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);     
     })
```

**RESULT :** Nothing Happens

**WHAT I WANT TO DO :** Update the Upvoters array and increment upvotes by 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to but both the `$inc` and `$push` operators into the same object:

```
Problem.findByIdAndUpdate(found_post[0].id,  
    { $inc: { upvotes : 1 }, 
      $push: { upvoters:  req.user.href }
    }, function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
})
```

Comment: OMG. Many Thanks!  :-)
I spent 2 hours trying to solve this. :-(

Comment: The right syntax is: `Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, [update], [options], [callback])`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate